# Unable to access Google Places API in GC Platform. How to access?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to access the Google Places API from my site, which is currently just a JS file on my laptop.

I've placed my HTTP file path in the [Key Restrictions section](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/key/) of the Google Cloud Platform console, but am still getting a CORS error.

How can I access the Google Places API?

Answer (score 0):

(CORS) stands for Cross-origin Resource Sharing and if you are getting `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` is likely an indication that the server must grant access to the requested resource to your remote domain by sending a Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. This is all answered in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141). Also see [How to use CORS to access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors).

That being said, programming question is more addressed on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) than Serverfault.